# How do I make a python script executable on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, python, cron, crontab, python3

Alternatively, I'm having trouble getting a crontab to run a python script, and I thought this would solve the problem. If you happen to know how to make a crontab run a python script, that would be great too :).